# How to draw a polygon on google map (V3) and save it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I use Google Map in my project and i customize it for create and drawing polygon and poly-line but i don't save shapes, and now i want create polygon on map and save it in my database, my question is : How to save polygon coords in my database?

My code:

```
  function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            minZoom: 14,
            maxZoom: 19,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.696282, 51.422946),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false                
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

          drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [/*google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE, google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE, */google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE, google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
            },
            polygonOptions: {
                editable: true
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function (event) {
            if (event.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {                    
                drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
                var newShape = event.overlay;
                newShape.type = event.type;
                google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
                    setSelection(newShape);
                });

                setSelection(newShape);
            }
        });            
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        //delete selected shape
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('deleteShape'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
```

}

Comment: Another answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800664/google-map-api-v3-how-to-get-coordinates-of-all-shapes/32807644#32807644

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = shape.getPath().getLength();
        var htmlStr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(shape.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(7));
        }
```